# Linked images via stylesheet

Tags: front-end, customization

When I work with lots of images, I don't always want them cooked into my notebook. This adds to the file bloat and if I change things externally I have to copy them back in.

Can I efficiently link my images dynamically via a TemplateBox construct? That way I can bind this to a stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example for how you can do such things via `TemplateBox`.

#### Linking in Action

We'll start with a demonstration then get to how it works.

First in a blank notebook (or one where overwriting the `StyleDefinitions` doesn't matter), evaluate:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/Stylesheets/LinkedImage.nb"]
  ];
```

Then we'll define a formatting [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) so we can access the [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox.html):

```
Format[LinkedImage[url_, alt : _String | Automatic : Automatic]] :=
  
  RawBoxes@
   TemplateBox[
    {
     url,
     If[alt === Automatic, 
      If[FileExistsQ@url, 
       FileNameTake[url],
       URLParse[url, "Path"][[-1]]
       ], 
      alt
      ]
     }, "LinkedImage"];
```

Then we can get one of these to load:

```
LinkedImage["https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8a4tt.png"]
```

[image: monkey]

But if we look at the boxes generated for that we see no excess data is baked into the notebook:

```
LinkedImage["https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8a4tt.png"] // ToBoxes

TemplateBox[{"https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8a4tt.png", "t8a4tt.png"}, "LinkedImage"]
```

This also works for local files:

```
LinkedImage[BTools`Paclets`AppPath["BTools", "PacletIconBig.png"]]
```

[image: boop]

And we can change what file or alt text we want by clicking on the image:

[image: click]

We can also extend this to images that stand in for links:

```
Format[LinkedImageLink[link_, 
   url : _String | Automatic : Automatic, 
   alt : _String | Automatic : Automatic]
  ] :=
 RawBoxes@
  TemplateBox[
   { 
    link,
    If[url === Automatic,  link, url],
    If[alt === Automatic, 
     If[FileExistsQ@link, 
      FileNameTake[link],
      URLParse[link, "Path"][[-1]]
      ],
     alt
     ]
    },
    "LinkedImageLink"
   ]
```

Then we can use a smaller image in our notebook, but link to a larger one which can be accessed via Command (or Control) click:

```
LinkedImageLink["https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8a4tl.png", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8a4tt.png", "monkey"]
```

[image: linker]

#### How do it do

We use a combination of `TemplateBox` system, `DynamicBox` with [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refresh.html), and caching of [`Imported`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) results.

The heart of this is making a `StyleData` cell in our stylesheet called `"LinkedImage"` and binding to it the [`DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html):

```
Function@
 TooltipBox[
  DynamicBox[
   Refresh[
    EventHandler[
     ToBoxes@
      Quiet[
       Check[Import[#],
         Framed[
         Style[#, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Serif"], 
         RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> GrayLevel[.95], 
         FrameStyle -> Gray]]
       ],
     {
      "MouseClicked" :>
       Replace[
        DialogInput[
         {alt = #2, link = #},
         Grid[
          {
           {"Image URL:", 
            EventHandler[
             InputField[Dynamic[link], String, BoxID -> "image-url"],
             "ReturnKeyDown" :>
              
              If[StringQ@alt && 
                AllTrue[{alt, link}, StringLength[#] > 0 &],
               DialogReturn[{link, alt}],
               FrontEndExecute@
                FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[
                 EvaluationNotebook[],
                 "alt-text"
                 ]
               ]
             ]},
           {"Alt Text:", 
            EventHandler[
             InputField[Dynamic[alt], String, BoxID -> "alt-text"],
             "ReturnKeyDown" :>
              
              If[StringQ@link && 
                AllTrue[{alt, link}, StringLength[#] > 0 &],
               DialogReturn[{link, alt}],
               FrontEndExecute@
                FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[
                 EvaluationNotebook[],
                 "image-url"
                 ]
               ]
             ]
             },
           {Spacer[{10, 10}]}
           },
          Alignment -> Left,
          Spacings -> {1, 1}
          ],
         WindowSize -> {300, All},
         WindowMargins ->
          Function[
            {{#[[1]], Automatic }, {Automatic, #[[2]]}}
            ][
           MousePosition[]
           ]
         ],
        {
          link_String,
          alt_String
          } :>
         NotebookWrite[
          Nest[ParentBox, EvaluationBox[], 3],
          TemplateBox[
           {
            link,
            alt
            },
           "LinkedImage"
           ]
          ]
        ],
      Method -> "Queued"
      }
     ],
    None
    ],
   TrackedSymbols :> {}
   ],
  #2
  ]
```

Now when one of these `TemplateBoxes` comes onto the screen the `DynamicBox` fires, tries to download the specified URL, and formats a little `EventHandler` that allows you to change its innards if you so choose. The results aren't cached beyond the `Refresh[..., None]` because we might want to change our file. Say I put something at `"https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/static_image.png"` and link against it:

```
LinkedImage["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.testing/static_image.png"]
```

[image]

But then if I change it I want to be able to reload and get the new image:

```
%
```

[image]

This is really all there is to it. It's a pretty simple concept, but with a pretty nice result.